# Display decoded URL in TextView with formatted text

Tags: java, android, textview

I have many strings that can contain text formatted using HTML tags and URL links. To display these strings, I use `Html.fromHtml()`, and this method perfectly displays formatted strings, but some links may containing non-English characters that look ugly cause of encoding.  I tried `URLDecoder.decode()` to decode the whole string, but it returns a `String` and this method corrupts the `Html.fromHtml()` that returns `Spanned`.  Is there a way to display both decoded links and formatted text in one text?

Example string:

```
<b>Hello</b> <i><u>stack</u></i> look https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A3%9E%E9%B9%B01%E7%BE%8E%E5%88%86%E7%A1%AC%E5%B8%81
```

[Result I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh7Vq.png)

Comment: have you tried `URLDecoder.decode()` before, or after `Html.fromHtml()`?

Comment: If i decode after `fromHtml()`, markup corrupting and TextView don't display it (URL looks as need, but all another text looks like usual text, without markup, bold not bold etc).
If i decode before, then URL returns still ugly after `fromHtml()`

Comment: well, you then will have to parse URL out, decode, and then put back in

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find the `charsetName` the get the string as shown in below and the get your HTML string.

```
byte[] arrByteForCharSet = drugName.getBytes("charsetName"); 
//for example: ISO-8859-1
String outputStr = new String(arrByteForCharSet);
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Html.fromHtml(URLDecoder.decode(decodedhtmlstring))
```

This will help